# Adding Lists and Strings and Importing the Current Year

Tags: python, list

This is my code for trying to figure out the age of someone accessing an 18+ website (https://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/3hrbpo/project_verifying_a_users_age/) I have two problems. 1) I could not figure out how to add the list websites to my else string. 2) I was wondering if there was a way for me to import the current year for currentDate so it wouldn't have to be put in manually. Thanks again and sorry for the sloppy code, I'm still new to Python!

```
import datetime


websites = ["www.youtube.com", "www.quora.com",    "www.twitter.com"]



while True:
    currentDate = 2015
    print("WARNING: THIS WEBSITE IS FOR 18 YEARS OR UP")
    userAge = int(raw_input("What is the year of your birth? "))
    if userAge + 18 <= currentDate:
        print "Welcome!"
        break
    elif userAge + 18 > currentDate:
        print ("We're sorry, but this website isn't for you, try some of these websites: ")
        continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

1. you want date.today() to get the current date
2. you want to use string.format() and string.join() to join the list together and insert its contents into your output
3. No need for the `elif` clause - `else` handles the "otherwise" condition (becuase your `elif` was opposite to your `if`)

Code:

```
from datetime import date

websites = ["www.youtube.com", "www.quora.com",    "www.twitter.com"]
while True:
    print("WARNING: THIS WEBSITE IS FOR 18 YEARS OR UP")
    userAge = int(raw_input("What is the year of your birth? "))
    if userAge + 18 <= date.today().year:
        print "Welcome!"
        break
    else:
        print ("We're sorry, but this website isn't for you, try some of these websites: {}".format(",".join(websites))
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be able to add the sites by adding to your code:

```
print("We're sorry, but this website isn't for you, try some of  these websites: " + websites[1] + ", " websites[2] + ", " websites[3]
continue
```

2. The date can be returned as a string by adding `import:time` to the top of your code and then using the function `time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Not sure why my code block wouldn't format, so I added the `